# Splitting Export large CSV files via Powershell

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, csv, filesystems

Like everyone know excel has got max rows  1048574. My question is :when the max row is reached, then move to a new CSV file I have tried something no luck I can't figure it out.

```
$RootFolder = Get-Content "c:\DRIVERS\myfile.txt"

foreach ($arrayOfPaths in $RootFolder){

  $csv  = $arrayofPaths -replace '^\\\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+).*', 'C:\output\Company_name_${1}_${2}.csv'
  Get-ChildItem $arrayOfPaths -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} | ForEach-Object {
$path = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$path}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
                  FileSystemRights |
    Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoType
  }

}
```

Last Update :

```
$RootFolder = Get-Content "c:\DRIVERS\myfile.txt"

foreach ($arrayOfPaths in $RootFolder){

  $csv  = $arrayofPaths -replace '^\\\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+).*', 'C:\output\Company_name_${1}_${2}.csv'
  $csvIndex = 1
  $maxRows = 1000000
  $rowsLeft = $maxRows

  Get-ChildItem $arrayOfPaths -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} | ForEach-Object {
  #$csv  = $_.FullName -replace '^\\\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+).*', 'C:\output\Company_name_${1}_${2}.csv'# <- construct CSV path here
  $path = $_.FullName
  $thisCSV = Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$path}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
                  FileSystemRights |
    ConvertTo-Csv
if ($thisCSV.count -lt $rowsLeft) {
    $thisCSV | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    $rowsLeft -= $thisCSV.count
} else {
    $thisCSV[0..($rowsLeft - 1)] | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    $csvIndex++
    $csv = $csv -replace '\.csv$', "$csvIndex.csv"
    if ($thisCSV.count -gt $rowsLeft) {
        $thisCSV[$rowsLeft..($thisCSV.count - 1)] | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    }
    $rowsLeft = $maxRows - ($thisCSV.count - $rowsLeft)
}


  }

}
```

Comment: @pnuts I have edited my question

Comment: I have to open CSVs files via Excel Application due to business requirements Because of that I want to split CSV file via powershell

Answer (score 0):

Do `ConvertTo-Csv` in a temporary variable, add up its `.Count` property until the split point is reached, then split the CSV array to a new file with a new name that will be used from this point on.

Below is a simplified example that assumes no single CSV can exceed 1000000 rows.

```
$csv = .............
$csvIndex = 1
$maxRows = 1000000
$rowsLeft = $maxRows

...........
$thisCSV = Select-Object ........ |
           ConvertTo-Csv
if ($thisCSV.count -lt $rowsLeft) {
    $thisCSV | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    $rowsLeft -= $thisCSV.count
} else {
    $thisCSV[0..($rowsLeft - 1)] | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    $csvIndex++
    $csv = $csv -replace '\.csv$', "$csvIndex.csv"
    if ($thisCSV.count -gt $rowsLeft) {
        $thisCSV[$rowsLeft..($thisCSV.count - 1)] | Export-Csv $csv -append -noType
    }
    $rowsLeft = $maxRows - ($thisCSV.count - $rowsLeft)
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much I dont understand that how can I adapted exactly your code. e.g $thisCSV = Select-Object ........    what require I do here ? So   do I have to use it after Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoType command at the end of code?

Comment: AFAIK  $thisCSV = Get-Acl $path | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$path}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
                  FileSystemRights |
    ConvertTo-Csv   Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I've overlooked the beginning of that line, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK but I have got a issue   I can not see any value related to the NTFS permissions instead of this  I can see with  "Length" column headers I assuming  there is logical error related to the syntax

Comment: Well, naturally I didn't debug the code, it just illustrates the concept.

Comment: BTW I have uploaded screenshots whats the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122175/discussion-between-arbelac-and-woxxom).